# SQL Server 2000 Exec (InsertString) Not Inserting All Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2000 that runs a bunch of `Exec` statements that all perform bulk inserts from a linked server to the local database. The linked server is a SQL Server 2012 instance.

This is a sample of the procedure:

```
Create Procedure CopyData(@LinkedServerName Varchar(10), @LinkedServerDatabase Varchar(20)) 
AS
BEGIN
    exec ('delete from table ConcernedTable')
    exec ('delete from table b')
    exec ('delete from table c')
    exec ('delete from table d')
.
.   
.
    exec ('delete from table z')

    exec ('insert into ConcernedTable select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].ConcernedTable')
    exec ('insert into b select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].b')
    exec ('insert into c select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].c')
    exec ('insert into d select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].d')
.
.
    exec ('insert into z select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].z')
END
```

I have a table (`ConcernedTable`) that has 100,000 rows on SQL Server 2012, but when I run the `Exec` statement to select from the SQL Server 2012 to the SQL Server 2000, it only inserts 12,768 rows.

I assumed my query had a bug, but it isn't the case. If I run the same `Exec` statement on a separate query window it inserts all the 100,000 rows. The even more weird thing is if I switch the position of the `exec` statement for my `ConcernedTable` as shown below it inserts all 100,000 rows.

```
Create Procedure CopyData(@LinkedServerName Varchar(10), @LinkedServerDatabase Varchar(20)) 
AS
BEGIN
    exec ('delete from table b')
    exec ('delete from table c')
    exec ('delete from table d')
.
.   
.
    exec ('delete from table z')
    exec ('delete from table ConcernedTable')


    exec ('insert into b select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].b')
    exec ('insert into c select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].c')
    exec ('insert into d select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].d')
.
.   
.
    exec ('insert into z select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].z')
    exec ('insert into ConcernedTable select * from ['+@LinkedServerName+'].['+@LinkedServerDatabase+'].[dbo].ConcernedTable')
END
```

The reason for making the Linkedserver name and Database name variables is there are multiple linked servers, thus did not want to create the same statement for each server.

Am I using the `Exec` statement incorrectly or is there something I need to do after the `exec` to ensure all rows are inserted before it moves to the next one?

Comment: The main question is: ***WHY*** are you using `Exec` at all?? Why not just have the `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements as such, in the procedure? What's the reason / point behind using `EXEC` for this??

Comment: marc is right here. I cant see why you are using EXEC when you have the insert statement there

Comment: Well Actually the data is pulled from multiple Linked servers, thus the linked server name and the linked server database are dynamic variables.

Comment: You still don't need to use `exec` for this. You use `exec` to call a procedure. You are merely using a variable inside a query IN a procedure.